# Why is my ViewGroup not listening to wrap_content?

Tags: java, android, view

In my Android application, I have a custom view (derives from ViewGroup), programmatically added to my activity.

```
rlParent.addView(myCustomView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I am settings the layoutParameters to WRAP_CONTENT. Still my application looks likes this:

[Go to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Xsh.png)

I added the red background to the custom view, so it becomes visible how much space it takes. Shouldn't it take just the amount of space it needs, so the big red line on the right shouldn't be there?

The tiles are custom views as well, I have added programmatically. What I'm trying to do is to center the custom view, so there's the same amount of space to the left as to the right.

Code (I've done all of it in Java, none in XML):

I call this method in the constructor. It adds all the FieldViews to the custom view. (A FieldView is a custom view that derives from RelativeLayout, it's just a tile on the screen).

```
private void fill() {
    for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
            FieldView fieldView = new FieldView(getContext(), r, c);
            mFieldViews.add(fieldView);

            addView(fieldView);
        }
    }
}
```

This is where I set the FieldView's position

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int childCount = getChildCount();

    int dimension = 10;
    int interval = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight()) / dimension;

    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        FieldView fieldView = (FieldView) getChildAt(i);

        int top = (i / dimension) * interval;
        int bottom = top + interval;
        int left = (i % dimension) * interval;
        int right = left + interval;

        fieldView.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

That's pretty much all code I can show...

Comment: Can you please post some of your code?

Comment: Sure thing, done it.

Comment: Can you show your `onMeasure`

Comment: I do not have an onMeasure method. Is this necessary?